# ALSA plug-in type empty

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I have often seen alsa configuration files with devices that uses plug-in type "empty". For example:

```
pcm.teeraw {
   type empty
   slave.pcm "tee:default,'/tmp/out.raw',raw"   
   # 48000 S16_LE 2ch (aplay -t raw -f dat)
}
```

However, there is no mention of it in the alsa documentation (http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html).

What does this plug-in explicitly do?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the `empty` plugin was copied/pasted from the `null` plugin, and never updated.

It does nothing; it redirects everything to its slave.

I don't know why anybody would use it; you can simply replace it with its slave.

Comment: The documentation says:
    "Plugin: Null

    This plugin discards contents of a PCM stream or creates a stream     with zero samples."


If empty is equivalent to null, then what is the point of having a slave if all the samples are discarded or taken as zero.

Comment: That documentation is wrong; it's the description of the `null` plugin.